# Difference in totalItems and actual items in google analytics api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to get profiles list https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list

Here is example from web version:

```
Request
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
Authorization:  Bearer
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
Response
200 OK

- Hide headers -

Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Tue, 09 Sep 2014 16:20:18 GMT
Etag:  "oq4YecK1DDgQfhLS-HzmxjZUB9I/ooSCrThtdvH0a3h5ysvIA31TDu0"
Expires:  Tue, 09 Sep 2014 16:20:18 GMT
Server:  GSE
Transfer-Encoding:  Identity

{
 "kind": "analytics#profiles",
 "username": "admin@domain.com",
 "totalResults": 38,
 "startIndex": 1,
 "itemsPerPage": 1000,
 "items": [
  ...
 ]
}
```

Here is my example ruby code using https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/ gem.

```
  def self.ga_client
    client = Google::APIClient.new(
      application_name: configatron.google_analytics.application_name,
      application_version: configatron.google_analytics.application_version
    )

    key_file = File.join(configatron.google_analytics.pk12_file_path)
    key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(key_file, 'notasecret')

    service_account = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
      configatron.google_analytics.service_email,
      configatron.google_analytics.scope,
      key
    )

    client.authorization = service_account.authorize

    client
  end


        client = self.ga_client
        analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics', configatron.google_analytics.version)

        result = client.execute(
          api_method: analytics.management.profiles.list,
          parameters: {
            accountId: "~all",
            webPropertyId: "~all"
          }
        )
    Response
    #<Google::APIClient::Result:0x00000108c71a10 @request=#<Google::APIClient::Request:0x00000108cc3f90 @parameters={"accountId"=>"~all", "webPropertyId"=>"~all"}, @headers={"User-Agent"=>"DLM/1.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.7.1 Mac OS X/10.9.3\n (gzip)", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip", "Content-Type"=>""}, @api_method=#<Google::APIClient::Method:0x8474c6b8 ID:analytics.management.profiles.list>, @authenticated=nil, @authorization=#<Signet::OAuth2::Client:0x000001013435a8 @token_credential_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x809a19e4 URI:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token>, @expiry=60, @extension_parameters={}, @additional_parameters={}, @scope=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction"], @issuer="filtered@developer.gserviceaccount.com", @principal=nil, @audience="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", @signing_key=#<OpenSSL::PKey::RSA:0x00000101341000>, @grant_type=nil, @refresh_token=nil, @code=nil, @issued_at=2014-09-09 20:19:07 +0400, @expires_in=3600, @access_token="ya29.ewBSHe0Wh5oGeKoe8aJtdpzVb-Nhr9SF0O39mdE1HgF3zTKs-8wBHL5M">, @body="">, @response=#<Faraday::Response:0x00000108c798c8 @on_complete_callbacks=[], @env=#<Faraday::Env @method=:get @body="{\"kind\":\"analytics#profiles\",\"username\":\"filtered@developer.gserviceaccount.com\",\"totalResults\":25,\"startIndex\":1,\"itemsPerPage\":1000,\"items\":...
```

From console it's only 25 records, why so? i'm tried to play with max-items option but have no luck, any hints?

Comment: Did you look to see which views are missing from your code results? My first thought is that you're making the request for two different user accounts, which I know has happened to me in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google API provides you options parameter

- max-results: It represents **itemsPerPage**.Default value is 1000
- start-index: Its represent the page no. Default value is 1

Hence I don't think changing values of max-items(max-results) will help because you have only 35 records. Using google console we are using different account(xyz@gmail.com) & for API we are using(XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com)

I tried with above options using google client and its shows me correct result.

**How I do it?**

1. I have total 13 GA accounts(xyz@gmail.com).
2. Given 11 account analytics readonly permission to **XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com**
3. Tried using GA Client library its shows me **totalResults=11** with its item detail(s).
4. Checked my profile results with OAuth 2.0 permission using [Views (Profiles): list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profiles/list#examples) play. It shows me **totalResults=13** records
5. Cross verified the google client API records by checking service name. It shows me the same service which I have granted access for developer email account **XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com**.

I am sure you have followed below steps. Please cross verify it once again.

1. Go to the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and create a new project
2. In the API Access tab, click Create an OAuth2.0 Client ID

   - Select the Service account option and press Create client ID
   - Download private key
   - Copy the Service Account Email address i.e. `XXXX@@developer.gserviceaccount.com`
   - Visit your [GA Admin](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#management/Accounts/) and add this email as a user to your properties
   - This is a must; you'll get cryptic errors otherwise.
3. Give Google Analytics Permission to my project using [Google Enable Api](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=analytics)
4. Get the latest Google [Ruby Client API](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/) via Gem

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"
   gem 'google-api-client', '>= 0.6'
   ```
5. Your API access Code. Mine is as below

   ```
   require 'google/api_client'
   require 'json'

   API_VERSION = 'v3'
   CACHED_API_FILE = "analytics-#{API_VERSION}.cache"

   # Update these to match your own apps credentials
   service_account_email = 'XYZ@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
   key_file = 'client.p12' # File containing your private key
   key_secret = 'notasecret' # Password to unlock private key


   client = Google::APIClient.new(
     :application_name => 'Plus Test', #Application name
     :application_version => '1')

   # Load our credentials for the service account
   key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
   client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
     :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
     :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
     :scope => ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
     :issuer => service_account_email,
     :signing_key => key)


   # Request a token for our service account
   client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

   analytics = nil
   # Load cached discovered API, if it exists. This prevents retrieving the
   # discovery document on every run, saving a round-trip to the discovery service.
   if File.exists? CACHED_API_FILE
     File.open(CACHED_API_FILE) do |file|
       analytics = Marshal.load(file)
     end
   else
     analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics', API_VERSION)
     File.open(CACHED_API_FILE, 'w') do |file|
       Marshal.dump(analytics, file)
     end
   end


   result = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.management.profiles.list, :parameters => {
     'alt' => "json",
     'accountId' => "~all",
     'webPropertyId' => "~all",
     'fields' => 'items(id,name,permissions,websiteUrl),itemsPerPage,startIndex,totalResults,username',
     'max-results' => 1, #used to get number of records. Default value is 1000
     'start-index' => 1 #This is page number. Default value is 1
   })

   #Response result
   result = JSON.parse(result.data.to_json)
   print result
   ```
6. Execute code using `bundle exec ruby test.rb`
7. Above code print the json of associated accounts.

**Conclusion:** Probably you have missed to give GA permission to some properties/accounts for developer email. Please cross verify the Actual GA Account(xyz@gmail.com) profile list with **XXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com**